# C# How do I loop through Images in a Listbox

Tags: c#, image, casting, listboxitem

I've created a listbox of Images and I want to resize all of them. I've got the method down but I cant seem to loop through the items in the listbox:

```
foreach (Image I in listbox1.items)
{
     Resize(I, x, y)
}
```

I get this error "unable to cast object of type system.string to type system.drawing.image". Any Ideas?

Earlier I was also using an Image cast on a listbox selected item:

```
Picturebox1.Image = (Image)listbox.selecteditem;
```

I remember it working, but it won't anymore. I'm assuming I remember the code wrong, any alternatives?

Comment: Show us the code that does ListBox.Items.Add, you're doing it wrong in that part of your code.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to put images in a ListBox, it doesn't know how to show them.  Clearly you put strings in it.  Your code cannot work with strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ListBox.Items.Add'ing wrong. Add the Image object, not a string path to the image or url or Image.ToString().

I get it now.. you're not doing ListBox.Items.Add(Image) because otherwise you see 'garbage' in the listbox, so the answer is to create a wrapper object:

```
class ImageWrapper
{
  public Image image;
  public string displayName;
  public override string ToString()
  {
    return displayName;
  }
}
```

then do

```
var iw = new ImageWrapper();
iw.image = <yourImage>;
iw.displayName = "Text for listbox here";
ListBox.Items.Add(iw);
```

Comment: I already have the Images in the listbox, adding them isn't the problem. It's getting them from the list box.

Comment: Wait, you're right. The image is never in the listbox only the name. Well, that's half a day of frustration for nothing. Thanks for the help